# jquery .get funciton with insert from input text line

Tags: jquery, get

So I have the following

```
<div id="myscore"><div>

<input type="text" name="score" id="score" />

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()   {
      $('#click').click(function(){
         $('#myscore').get('computescore.php', $('#score').val(); )});
 });
```

```
<div id="click">   <a href="#">click</a>   </div>
```

The code will not pick up the value of score. How do you get the value of an input field into the a jquery function?

It updates the myscore field with the computed score after the score has been entered and clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `computescore.php` just returns a single value, change:

```
$('#myscore').get('computescore.php', $('#score').val(); )});
```

to

```
$('#myscore').get(
    'computescore.php',
    function(data){ $('#score').val(data); }
);
```

you have to use a callback-function. take a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

$("#score").val() will get you the current value correctly. I'm assuming you want to do something liek this, i.e. set the value of the text to what computescore.php returns?

```
$(document).ready(function()   {
      $('#click').click(function(){
         $('#myscore').get('computescore.php', function(data){
              $('#score').val(data);
         }); 
      });
 });
```